# Hide Columns in a range based on cell value selected from drop-down

Tags: excel, vba

Thank you PGSystemTest and Alexey for your comments.  2nd attempt.
Here’s what I need to do:

1. Select one or more departments from a list, the rest of the department rows will be hidden. (orange arrow)
2. Select from a list A, B, or C and display only columns in the task range (orange) that contain the selection.
3. Show All Rows and Columns again.

The departments are in G25:G37

The Orange Range of Tasks is I25:DM37

[matrix sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygKka.png)

Below is what I started doing to loop through the range to hide the columns.

```
    Sub Hide_Columns_Containing_A()
       'Description: This macro will loop through the row and
       'hide the column if the cell in the column
       'has the value of A.

    
      Dim c As Range

      For Each c In Range("I25:DM37").Cells
        If c.Value = "A" Then
            c.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

        End If
      Next c

    End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, this isn't very clear. I don't see anything in the bottom right, and your columns don't have headers. Try to replicate your question with something simple that isolates your problem. We (SO)  want to help you, but you gotta give us something meaningful to work with.

Comment: What do you do with values besides A, when you have filtered the row and columns? Do you need to count the values? If yes, may be a pivot table will suit you?

Comment: Reposted - hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: How do you `select` the `departments`, and how do you `select` `A` `B` and/or `C`.  Is there a data validation list somewhere, or do you use some other means?

Comment: Currently I have validation list on a "list" sheet, but it could be a list or combo box if that works better.

Comment: If you want someone to see you've responded to their comments, you need to 'tag' them (for example) like this: `@kevin9999`.  What you're asking for is very possible, but you'll need to provide a lot more information - see next comment.

Comment: **1.** What are the names of the two sheets containing the `matrix` and the `validation` lists? **2.** what is the cell range containing the list of departments on the matrix sheet? **3.** what is the range of columns containing the `A` `B` etc. cells?   **4.** what cells contain the validation dropdowns on the 'lists' sheet? **5.** are you familiar with `Worksheet_Change` event procedures?